# MySQL DataGridView bind

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have the following code to connect to a MySql server

```
    Dim oConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim sConnStr As String
    Dim oDbAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim oTable As Data.DataTable
    sConnStr = String.Format("Server=localhost;User=user; Password=pass; Database=db; Pooling=false") '
    oConn = New MySqlConnection(sConnStr)
    oConn.Open()
    oTable = New Data.DataTable()
    oDbAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test", oConn)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = oTable
    oDbAdapter.Fill(oTable)
```

This code works, however, when I switch the order of the last two row

```
    Dim oConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim sConnStr As String
    Dim oDbAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim oTable As Data.DataTable
    sConnStr = String.Format("Server=localhost;User=user; Password=pass; Database=db; Pooling=false") '
    oConn = New MySqlConnection(sConnStr)
    oConn.Open()
    oTable = New Data.DataTable()
    oDbAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test", oConn)
    oDbAdapter.Fill(oTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = oTable
```

When I'm using step by step, I noticed that the command run to the .fill command and then just skipped assigning it to the DataGridView.

Not sure why is this happening, since it would make much more sense that "after getting the data from SQL, assign it to datagridview"

PS: the datagridview is just an empty grid with nothing assigned in it.

Comment: Is that code in the `Load` event handler of the form?  If so then my guess would be that the `Fill` call is throwing an exception, which are swallowed silently in that location.  Try wrapping the code in an exception handler to find out.

Comment: By the way, don't `Open` the connection and then call `Fill` without closing the connection again.  There's no need or point to calling `Open` yourself if all you're doing is calling `Fill` or `Update` once.  Both of those methods will open a connection implicitly and, even better, close it again if - but ONLY if - it opened it in the first place.  By opening it yourself you tell the `Open` method not to close it but then you don't close it either.  Bad.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I did close it in my script, just showing as an example